# Typescript lookup types - correctly narrow down properties set when merging with Partial

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.1

I'm playing with lookup types and would like to build kind of safe-merge util function (one that takes entity of type `T` and an object containing subset of keys of `T` to update). My goal is to let compiler tell me when I misspell a property or try to append non-existing one for `T`.

So I have `Person` and use built-in `Partial` in (v2.1) like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  active: boolean
}

function mergeAsNew<T>(a: T, b: Partial<T>): T {
  return Object.assign({}, a, b);
}
```

Now I apply this to the following data:

```
let p: Person = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 33,
  active: false
};

let newPropsOk = {
  name: 'john doe',
  active: true
};

let newPropsErr = {
  fullname: 'john doe',
  enabled: true
};

mergeAsNew(p, newPropsOk);
mergeAsNew(p, newPropsErr); // <----- I want tsc to yell at me here because of trying to assign non-existing props
```

I would like TS compiler to yell at me on the second invocation as `fullname` and `enabled` aren't props of `Person`. Unfortunately this compiles fine locally, but... when I do the same in [online TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20active%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20mergeAsNew%3CT%3E(a%3A%20T%2C%20b%3A%20Partial%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20a%2C%20b)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p%3A%20Person%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20'john'%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20age%3A%2033%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20active%3A%20false%20%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newPropsOk%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20'john%20doe'%2C%0D%0A%20%20active%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newPropsErr%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fullname%3A%20'john%20doe'%2C%0D%0A%20%20enabled%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20active%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmergeAsNew(p%2C%20newPropsOk)%3B%0D%0AmergeAsNew(p%2C%20newPropsErr)%3B) I get more or less what I expect:

```
The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'Person' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate '{ fullname: string; enabled: boolean; }'.
    Property 'name' is missing in type '{ fullname: string; enabled: boolean; }'.
```

Looks like the playground uses the same version as I do locally (2.1.4). Does anybody have a clue why these two may differ?

**Bonus question:**

when I try the following assignment:

```
let x: Person = mergeAsNew(p, newPropsOk);
```

I get the following error on `x` but only on the playground (it's all fine locally):

```
Type '{ name: string; active: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
  Property 'age' is missing in type '{ name: string; active: boolean; }'.
```

Why is that? Shouldn't it *be* of `Person` type, as first `mergeAsNew` argument **is** `Person` and and everything else is `Person`-props subset (so it's at most `Person`)?

**EDIT**
Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["dist", "scripts"]
}
```

Comment: It's because type inference looks for every field. If you put the for example **fullname** property as optional **fullname?** it should work properly. Or, you should provide every field that match the object contract.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `2.1.4` version? Maybe your IDE uses something else?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, it's 2.1.4.everywhere. I even do `tsc` from command line to make sure IDE doesn't trick me here.

Comment: @Fals not sure if I get you right. `fullname` and `enabled` are both fields I don't want to sneak into my `p` being `Person`. This is exactly what I want to do, allow only props defined in `Person` to be overridable (and not necessary all at once)

Comment: @MichalOstruszka The object that you wan't to return has nothing to do with Person. TypeScript is strongly typed, then you should properly create classes that match's the expected type.

Comment: You're right, it behaves the same for me (running `2.1.4`). A bug?

Comment: @Fals I don't think so. If you take a look at `Object.assign` signature in this case, it's: `(method) ObjectConstructor.assign<{}, T, Partial<T>>(target: {}, source1: T, source2: Partial<T>): {} & T & Partial<T>` so it IS `T`

Comment: @NitzanTomer not sure yet, tried with latest 2.2 and it's the same result. Even if it's a bug - why it behaves differently locally and on playground?

Comment: @MichalOstruszka you are wrong,  age is not optional property, the compiler is yelling for this! if you are assigning an object without the constructor creation using new your must match the entire contract.

Comment: @Fals but the resulting object already gets `age` and other `Person` props from the first argument (of type `Person`). I just want to override some of them later on (with `b`)

Comment: @MichalOstruszka You should post your tsconfig then, there's probably a compilerOptionsDefinition supressing this error I'm suspecting of suppressExcessPropertyErrors or noImplicitAny.

Comment: @Fals edited my question adding `tsconfig.json`. Unfortunately looks like it's none of these two options you mentioned that causes the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

When you want to express that one type has only a subset of properties from another type, plain old `extends` can help too

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
    active: boolean
}


let p: Person = {
    name: 'john',
    age: 33,
    active: false
};

let newPropsOk = {
    name: 'john doe',
    active: true
};

let newPropsErr = {
  fullname: 'john doe',
  enabled: true
};

// a extends b and not the other way round
//because we don't want to allow b to have properties not in a
function mergeAsNew<T2, T1 extends T2>(a: T1, b: T2): T1 {
    return Object.assign({}, a, b);
}

mergeAsNew(p, newPropsOk); // ok
mergeAsNew(p, newPropsErr); 
// Argument of type 'Person' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '{ fullname: string; enabled: boolean; }'.
//   Property 'fullname' is missing in type 'Person'.
```

PS no idea what's going on with playground and mapped types

Comment: This is not quite what I had in mind. In your code this `extends` causes second argument `T2` to contain all `T1` props + some extras. What I want to do is `T2` to contain subset of `T1` props (and be type-checked in compile time)

Comment: No, `T1 extends T2` means that T1 has everything that is in T2, so T2 can not contain any extras: `mergeAsNew(p, newPropsErr);` gives an error about extra properties in newPropsErr - is that not what you needed?

Comment: Argh, missed that it's `T1 extends T2` not the other way around. Yeah, looks like it should do what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I was too fixed on that yesterday. I got some sleep and it looks like it's (probably) impossible to do what I want that way (using `Partial`). Leaving this weird playground behaviour aside for a while, here is why (at least I think so):

To recap:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  active: boolean
}

function mergeAsNew<T>(a: T, b: Partial<T>): T {
  return Object.assign({}, a, b);
}
```

In this code, `Partial<Person>` may (but **doesn't have to**) contain any of `Person` props, so the following is perfectly valid `Partial<Person>` type:

```
let newPropsErr = {
  fullname: 'john doe',
  enabled: true
};
```

As Typescript has structural typing it doesn't care about extra props, it checks only shape of the object and here shape fits `Partial<Person>` just fine.

The only way to somehow check argument's shape agains `Partial<Person>` for extra props is to pass it as object literal (literals are strictly checked to match type)

Now to `mergeAsNew` function itself. I do `Object.assign` here which does exactly what it's designed for - merges props from both args into new object (all of them). Because types are only for TS compilation, there is no way in runtime to constraint and selectively pick props from `b` and apply them to override `a` props.

Looks like [@Artem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603003/2153664)  that does what I need with `extend` and no mapped/lookup types.

Anyway, I still don't get why TS Playground works the way it works (what initially give me an impression that all that stuff is perfectly doable).